# VBA Editor on F8 shows outlook insted of Step Into

Tags: vba, excel

Excel VBA Editor on F8 shows Outlook instead of Step Into. I don`t use it and it wants me to add my e-mail configuration every time.
In other applications F8 works properly.
What am I doing wrong?

Windows 7 x64

Comment: Are you by any chance trapping the `F8` anywhere? Check the workbook_open or is there an Add-in which is doing that?

Comment: Also just a quick check. Click on Debug menu in the vba editor. What is the shortcut key that is displayed for "Step Into"?

Comment: In excel F8 makes selection box (no Outlook).In VBA Debug menu "Step Into - F8"

Comment: wait let me get this straight. You are doing this in Excel-VBA right?

Comment: Have you defined F8 as macro Shortcut, or have some control key pressed...

Comment: Yes Excel VBA as I wrote in description )

Comment: No macro on F8, no plugings and contols. Rebooting helped for a while, but now Outlook appears again on F8.

Comment: This problem is happening to me, not with the F8 key, but when I expand a tree in Local Variables window.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer! Your "function" key on your keyboard is set to "on." Shortcut automatically opens up outlook. I was having the same issue, and just realized.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing just happened to me.
I just configured my email again and now F8 is back working normally.